# How to use combobox.Text after Keydown event in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, text, combobox, keydown

I am using a combobox without the dropdown to accept text input only. On the windows form I have an OK button which calls a function that uses the combobox.Text property.

The problem is that I want to call this function when the user types something then hits ENTER. I am trying to handle the KeyDown event (I have tried other events with much the same results) but I find that combobox.Text is null after this is fired. I want something like this to work ideally:

```
private void cbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyValue == 13)
        {
            OK(cbox.Text); 
        }
    }
```

Why is combobox.Text wiped after the KeyDown event? This same problem wouldn't happen with a Textbox right? I'm nearly desperate enough but I don't want to replace this box on every form in the program lol... Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have more than one ComboBox on your form?  The event is for `cbox` but you are getting the text result from `cbo`.

I would suggest changing you code to this:

```
private void cbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
     {
          string result = cbox.Text;
     }
}
```

Comment: Oh no sorry, that was just a typo in the example that I tried to make as clear as possible. There is only one ComboBox and the above does not work for me I'm afraid - by the time OK() is called, cbox.Text is an empty string.

Comment: I have amended the example above.  What happens if you replace your method OK() with string result = cbox.Text;  Do you have any other events acting on the text of the ComboBox?

Comment: I tried that previously when debugging - result is null and cbox.Text = "" as far as I can see. I don't think there are any other events acting on the combobox, the text disappearing just seems to happen on the KeyDown event for some reason?

Comment: Interesting! :)  What properties have you set on the ComboBox e.g. DropDownStyle, AutoComplete etc..

Comment: Thanks for the hint - it turns out the problem was AutoComplete, I needed to set this to none as found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/16d66cab-6c85-4e2d-b79a-a2338bc27402/

Comment: Excellent, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

When pressing Enter the ComboBox cleans the Text before event occurs because you set the AutoCompleteMode.

Just change it to none.

```
cbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
```